# Can send email but can not receive email on Windows Server 2012 R2 with MailEnable

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

I am configuring a VPS on Windows Server 2012 R2 using MailEnable as email server.

As the port 25 is blocked by ISP so I use port 587 instead.[image]

When configuring on email client Outlook or ThunderBird, it all passed test and I am able to receive test message from outlook.
[image]
Below is my Outlook setting:
[image]

**However, I am not being able to receive any test email when I try to send from gmail or hotmail, etc.**

I checked the server firewall and port 25 is open.

Can anyone please help with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TCP port 587 is for mail submission from **clients**. Receiving email from other mail servers **requires** TCP port 25. You'll need to either move your server elsewhere or get your ISP to open that port.

You will also want to un-check the "authentication required" option, as remote mail servers have no way of authenticating themselves to your server.

Comment: The server is hosted by LimeStone and I don't think they can open port 25 for me. And I do receive email from Outlook test email though.

Comment: Then move the server to a provider that does not have ridiculous limitations on their service.

Comment: Regarding your comment - mail submission from a client is completely different than receiving mail from a remote mail server. In this instance, the fact that one works and the other doesn't is completely expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change SMTP port 587 to 25. (This is for remote servers sending you e-mail.)
2. Untick the authentication requirement.
3. Get on Submission Port and enable listening on alternate port as 587. (This is for your server sending email.)
4. Tick the authentication requirement here for unauthorized sendings.